# Will copy database for one instance will impact performance for another instance in SQL Azure server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

this is my first post,and i am trying my best to make my question clear. pls forgive me if i failed to do so :)

Here's the situation:
 - 1 sql azure server ABC. 
 - 2 database instances in that server, ABC1 (my backup database) and ABC2(my live database)

This morning, I created a new database by from ABC1, and at the same time some users complained about performance issue they have in live environment( which is using ABC2 db). So I am wondering if it's possible that copying one db instance will impact performance to another db instance in the same server.

Command I used(inside XYZ sql azure server):

CREATE database XYZ1 as copy of ABC.ABC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the server you refer to in Azure SQL Database is just a logical one and does not correspond to an actual physical server. The databases you create in that logical server maybe on different SQL nodes in Azure.

Rather than guess what's causing the performance issue, have a look at the Azure SQL DMVs/system views to see if the stats you get gives an indication about the performance degradation

Answer (score 1):

The performance of a Azure SQL Database is largely dependent on the Service-Tier and the performance level, which comes with an associated billing.

Please refer this link for more information, [Azure-Service-Tier and Performance-Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx)